# Racial abilities in Lord of the Rings: War in the North

Tags: lotr-war-in-the-north

I'm playing as a Ranger in LOTR:WITN and from what I can tell, my racial ability is to be able to see "glowing footsteps" from other Rangers and find secret stashes. This has happened twice in about 6 completed missions. My brother-in-law is playing as the Elven mage and is able to collect plants etc to be used in crafting potions, and he's doing that all the time. The (AI-controlled) dwarf seems to have a battle cry of some sort which he performs 20 times a mission.

It seems that I got hosed in the racial ability stakes, is that correct? Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this forum post](http://www.warinthenorth.com/forums/showthread.php?t=781) (and you have to read down for a correction), these are the "special abilities" for each race:

- Rangers (Human): see the hidden tracks of animals or other creatures
- Elves: Collect herbs for making potions
- Dwarves: See and break into weak places in walls/doors